# Use IronPython to run Python code which use MySQL Connector thrown exception

Tags: c#, python, mysql, ironpython

When I use IronPython to call my Python method， it thrown an Exception:

> An exception of type “IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.TypeErrorException” occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Other information: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'bytearray' and 'str'.

Here are my C# code:

```
public static void doPython()
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
    paths.Add(@"D:\WorkSoft\ATTOptimize\test_python\");
    paths.Add(@"D:\Python\Lib");
    paths.Add(@"D:\Python\Lib\site-packages");
    //my python installed in "D:\Python"
    engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"D:\WorkSoft\mysqlConnection.py");
}
```

And this is my Python code:

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='1qaz2wsx', host='127.0.0.1', database='db_mes')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = "SELECT testId,testResult FROM db_mes.test "
cursor.execute(query)

for (testId,testResult) in cursor:
    print testId,testResult

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

When I run my c# code it thrown that exception, can anyone tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: Put also you Python code in your question (not as a link). Did you C# code fail at line ExecuteFile?

Comment: Thank you first，my python code operation nomally，but when i called it in c# ,It has such an error message。Previously, I submitted my python code when there is no alignment, it was not the way to use the link

Comment: I have remoed the picture.others：my python version is 2.7.13,and IronPython‘s version is 2.7.7 ，mySql version is 5.7,and My operating system is 64-bit win7，The net framework  from version 4.0 to version 4.7 shows this error。